# Airflow 2.0.1 filter DAGs by owner

Tags: airflow, superuser

How can I restrict the DAGs that are related to a particular owner in airflow 2.0.1?

I have enabled the
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQdwG.png)

Answer (score -1):

That configuration item was removed and it's not available in Airflow 2.

As mentioned [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html):

> As part of this change, a few configuration items in [webserver] section are removed and no longer applicable, including `authenticate`, `filter_by_owner`, `owner_mode`, and `rbac`.

You can implement this using LDAP authentication, using groups and permissions. You can find all the details in [this video](https://youtu.be/s6TygwvYdN0?t=812) (I included the specific time when it configures the role).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I achieve this using LDAP Authentication?

Comment: @PradeepReddy, I changed the whole answer since it's possible with LDAP.

Comment: @bruo-uy The DAG filtering built-upon RBAC is based on DAG name. Imagine you have tons of flow, you keep modifying the customized roles?